# how to change chart JS title text on change input field?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I have a chart JS and On the top of it I have an input field. when I want to do is to let the user type whatever he wants on the input field and when he finish typing on this input field. then his chart JS title text changes to what he wrote in the input field. so in the image below this box contains "Chart Title" is an input field. I want the user to type there and when its done then the chart title text "This is a chart" changes to what's written in the input field.
[image]

HTML

```
<input  type="text" style="border:1px solid white;background-color: #E9E8E6; color: black;  text-align: center;" placeholder = "Chart Title">    <!--The input field that takes user input and when its done I want to change the chart JS title text which have the text "This is a chart" to be changed to the input field text -->
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                      <canvas id="barChart_3"></canvas>
```

JS

```
 var dzSparkLine = function(){
    let draw = Chart.controllers.line.__super__.draw; //draw shadow
    
    var screenWidth = $(window).width();
    

    
    var barChart3 = function(){
        //stalked bar chart
        if(jQuery('#barChart_3').length > 0 ){
            const barChart_3 = document.getElementById("barChart_3").getContext('2d');
            //generate gradient
            const barChart_3gradientStroke = barChart_3.createLinearGradient(50, 100, 50, 50);
            barChart_3gradientStroke.addColorStop(0, "rgba(19, 180, 151, 1)");
            barChart_3gradientStroke.addColorStop(1, "rgba(19, 180, 151, 0.5)");

            const barChart_3gradientStroke2 = barChart_3.createLinearGradient(50, 100, 50, 50);
            barChart_3gradientStroke2.addColorStop(0, "rgba(43, 193, 85, 1)");
            barChart_3gradientStroke2.addColorStop(1, "rgba(43, 193, 85, 1)");

            const barChart_3gradientStroke3 = barChart_3.createLinearGradient(50, 100, 50, 50);
            barChart_3gradientStroke3.addColorStop(0, "rgba(208, 116, 7, 1)");
            barChart_3gradientStroke3.addColorStop(1, "rgba(208, 116, 7, 1)");
            
            barChart_3.height = 100;
          
            let barChartData = {
                defaultFontFamily: 'Poppins',
                labels: [ 2023,2024,2025,2026,2027],
                datasets: [100,200,500,700,800]     };

            new Chart(barChart_3, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: barChartData,
                options: {
                    legend: {
                        display: true,
                        position: 'right'
                    }, 
                    title: {
                        display: true,text: 'This is a chart'        // the text I want to change
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        mode: 'index',
                        intersect: false
                    },
                    responsive: true,
                        scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: ''
          }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Years'
          }
        }],
      }
    
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to put your `new Chart` into a variable that is accessible in your function that runs when your user is done typing.

After this you can call:

```js
chartVariable.options.title.text = userInput;
chartVariable.update();
```

See fiddle link where after chart creation I update title to dddd from ffff: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/0vxcwqft/4/

Comment: Your answer worked for me after a tiny change:  I have added `plugins` after `options`.  Like this: `chartVariable.options.plugins.title.text`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to change the built-in title, but you can hide it or omit it and use a regular heading element instead, if that works for you then this is a working solution

One way to do that is to listen to the input value changing and then grabbing it every time it changes and adding it to the title, like this:

```js
var chartTitleInput = document.getElementById("chart-title-input");
var chartTitle = document.getElementById("chart-title")

chartTitleInput.addEventListener("change", function(){
  var title = chartTitleInput.value;
  chartTitle.textContent = title;
})
```

```html
<input id="chart-title-input" type="text">
<h1 id="chart-title"></h1>
```

I used the `change` event but you can use `keyup` or `keydown` events if you like. `change` event will only fire when the value of the input changes and every time it changes. The user will be able to see changes when they press enter or leave the input field (the input field loses focus) only if the current value isn't the same as the previous value though because then the `change` event won't fire, while a `keyup` event will fire, for example.

Answer (score 0):

the title is an object containing the text and some attributes:

```
let myTitle = {
    text: 'my chart title',
    color: 'green',
};
```

in the recent versions of chart js the title is a plugin, so:

if you put the title in the config before creating the chart,

```
let chartConfig = {
...
};
chartConfig.options.plugins.title = myTitle;
let chart = new Chart(ctx, chartConfig);
```

you may also set it in the already displaying chart:

```
chart.options.plugins.title = myTitle;
```